# How to make Use of String startswith and equalsIgnoreCase for string array object

Tags: android

I have to place selected particular set of string from String Array into another array, here I need to combine both `equalsIgnorecase` with String `startsWith` method.

If I have comparator:

```
String a= "j";
if(a.startswith("j"))
```

it returns true only "j", but here i need  "J" and "j" has case sensitive, how can I get this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What? Restate the question so that it makes sense plz.

Comment: I think he wants a case-insensitive `startsWith()` method. That's my best guess, anyhow. Or he wants to implement one, maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if("j".equalsIgnoreCase(a.substring(0, 1)))

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is this.

```
String a = "Joker";
if((a.substring(0,1)).equalsIgnoreCase("j")) doSomething();
```